# Table of Contents causes a $ error in XeTEX

Tags: table-of-contents, xetex, compilation-error

I've included my whole file below. This causes a $ error when run. When I run it with the \tableofcontents commented out it works. Weird thing: Only in XeLaTeX (with MakeIndex and BibTex). It was working fine in PDFLatex but my project needs XeLaTeX. I've reduced the situation to this small file which can be run. How do I get the \tableofcontents command to work?

```
\documentclass[14pt]{extarticle}                % bigger font easier for kids on test

\usepackage{fontspec}                              %  sanserif with xelatex

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents


\section{Definitions - 9 pts}
\subsection{question \ref{sec:tanquestion}: (3 pts)} \label{sec:tanquestion}
\end{document}
```

It causes this error:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error doesn't show up with `pdflatex` (if you remove `\usepackage{fontspec}`), but just by chance.

You need to use `\protect\ref` when `\ref` is in a “moving argument”.

```
\documentclass[14pt]{extarticle}                % bigger font easier for kids on test

\usepackage{fontspec}                              %  sanserif with xelatex

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents


\section{Definitions - 9 pts}
\subsection{question \protect\ref{sec:tanquestion}: (3 pts)} \label{sec:tanquestion}

\end{document}
```

On the other hand, I don't see the need for repeating the number in the subsection header.

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! That’s perfect! (I’m designing a math test with diagrams drawn using pstricks and need the questions to be modular so that they’re in the toc. There’s actually 10 questions with a ton of stuff and all. )